# Why treeview checkbox doesn't appear when using template?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-template

The current problem is that the checkbox doesn't appear in my kendo treeview. The reason of using the template is i wanted to define the checkbox name where it is more easily to handle the checked event but i'm not sure the format of the template is correct.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="treeview" data-role="treeview" data-template="treeviewtemplate" data-text-field="text" data-checkboxes='{"checkChildren": true,template:checkboxtemplate}' data-value-field="value"></div>
  
  <script id="treeviewtemplate" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
     #= item.text #
  </script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function checkboxtemplate(e){
     return "#if(!item.hasChildren){#<input type='hidden' parent_id='#=item.parent_id#' d_text='#=item.value#' /><input type='checkbox' name='checkedFiles[#= item.value #]' value='true' />#}else{#<input type='checkbox' parent_id='#=item.parent_id#' d_text='#=item.value#' /> #}#"
     }
  </script>
  
  <script>
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dataSource: {
  data: [
    { id      : 5,
     parent_id: 0,
     text    : "General - Primary Probe",
     value    : "General - Primary Probe",
     expanded : true,
     items    : [
       { id: 51, parent_id: 5, text: "Agent Running Mode",value:"priProbeARM"},
       { id: 52, parent_id: 5, text: "Agent Version",value:"priProbeAV"},
       { id: 53, parent_id: 5, text: "Master/Slave Mode",value:"priProbeMSM"},
       { id: 54, parent_id: 5, text: "Manufacturer",value:"priProbeManu"},
       { id: 55, parent_id: 5, text: "Model",value:"priProbeModel"},
       { id: 56, parent_id: 5, text: "Software Version",value:"priProbeSV"}
     ]}]
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="treeview"></div>
<script id="treeviewtemplate" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
     #if(!item.hasChildren){#
     <input type='hidden' parent_id='#=item.parent_id#' d_text='#=item.value#' /><input type='checkbox' name='checkedFiles[#=item.value #]' value='true' />#}else{#<input type='checkbox' parent_id='#=item.parent_id#' d_text='#=item.value#' /> #}#
     #= item.text#
</script>
  
<script>
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  template:kendo.template($("#treeviewtemplate").html()),
  dataTextField:"text",
  dataValueField:"value",
  dataSource: {
  data: [
    { id      : 5,
     parent_id: 0,
     text    : "General - Primary Probe",
     value    : "General - Primary Probe",
     expanded : true,
     items    : [
       { id: 51, parent_id: 5, text: "Agent Running Mode",value:"priProbeARM"},
       { id: 52, parent_id: 5, text: "Agent Version",value:"priProbeAV"},
       { id: 53, parent_id: 5, text: "Master/Slave Mode",value:"priProbeMSM"},
       { id: 54, parent_id: 5, text: "Manufacturer",value:"priProbeManu"},
       { id: 55, parent_id: 5, text: "Model",value:"priProbeModel"},
       { id: 56, parent_id: 5, text: "Software Version",value:"priProbeSV"}
     ]}]
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe you should try to insert the checkbox element into your tree template script. And then, render your template script with tree template configuration like this,

`template : template:kendo.template($("#treeviewtemplate").html())`,

You can also add some styles/classes or extra label element to make your template checkbox look like standart kendo checkboxes.

I also recommend you to use kendo tree configurations to create extra attributes such as dataTextField, dataValueField.. rather than adding these as div placeholder element attributes:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            dataTextField:"text",
            dataValueField:"value",..})
```